# Create tagSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES object

Tags: winapi, autoit

Using `_WinAPI_CreateFileMapping()` I want to enable a different user on the same machine to receive messages via `_WinAPI_OpenFileMapping()`. I am receiving errors when I try to open the file mapping (`invalid handle error #6`), because of the security settings maybe.

I found [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/96622817-2e2f-4871-9fda-01fe9389f127/how-to-createfilemapping-with-security-attributes-that-allow-crossuser-access?forum=csharpgeneral) about file mappings and allowing cross user access.    The solution was to create a NULL security identifier (not passing NULL, but passing a valid security identifier, containing NULL):

```
SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.NullSid, null);
```

How do I create this in AutoIt and pass it to `_WinAPI_CreateFileMapping()`?

Sending side script (running as local user):

```
Local $sid = _Security__StringSidToSid("S-1-0")     ; also tried S-1-1
$hMapping = _WinAPI_CreateFileMapping(-1, 2048, 'MyFileMapping',0x0004,$sid)  ;it seems to accept the sid
DllStructSetData($tData, 1, "IDL")  ; if($hMapping)  send the message...
```

Receiving service script (running as system account):

```
$hMapping = _WinAPI_OpenFileMapping('MyFileMapping')
```

Also tried passing read-only. `0x0004` returns `0x0000` file handle / `0` error `0` extended. Once a `1305` error code (can't duplicate that).

```
;  if($hMapping) ... this is how I am trying to receive the message:
$pAddress = _WinAPI_MapViewOfFile($hMapping)
$tData = DllStructCreate('wchar[1024]', $pAddress)
$Text = DllStructGetData($tData, 1)
DllStructSetData($tData, 1, '')
```

Comment: I've got no idea what `$sid` is (I've never used these functions before) but it seems you want to be passing something like [this](http://pad.mattdiesel.co.uk/tag-security-descriptor-null) to `_WinAPI_CreateFileMapping`, at least that's how I interpret the page you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Try `S-1-0-0` instead of `S-1-0`

**[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**